# Span in vue return [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, promise

I launch my function `getOrderCount` in my `table` in vue component, he return me only number of the orders to one of the column i table,

```
<div v-html="getOrderCount(user.orders_url)"></div>
```

```
async getOrderCount(link) {
        const count = await this.getOrderCount(link);
        return `<span class="p-1">${count}</span>`
 },
```

but why on my table is not `number` but `object Promise`?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3gXy.png)

thanks for any help and solution

Comment: That's becoz you contain a request in that method which can't be rendered instantly..and moreover you are calling it recursively

Answer (score -1):

Async function always returns a promise. If you return to number 1, it will actually return a promise that resolves into a number 1.

I hope this example will give you inspiration about how to solve your issue.

```
<template>
   <div>{{count}}</div>
</template>

<script>
    async getOrderCount(link) {
   const count = await this.getOrderCount(link);
   return `<span class="p-1">${count}</span>`
},

export default {
   data() {
      return {
         orderCount: 0
      }
   },
   async created () {
      this.count = await this.getOrderCount(this.props.link);
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: No, i cant do that because i must launch my function via `v-html` in component cause i need to past argument from `for-each` in table...

Comment: Can you provide a full example of a code, I'm sure I can help you once I have the full picture.
And just so you know, when you add -1 to someone's comment, that damages their reputation points. That is perfectly fine, but since we are still discussing and I'm still trying to help you, maybe you shouldn't jump to it that fast :-)